# No Internet in Ubuntu with new CPU, motherboard and SSD

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, ssd

I don’t have Internet on a machine that has a new motherboard and new CPU.

What can be done to get internet connectivity again?

Also installed a new CPU and motherboard.

- **CPU**: 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-12500

Here is the BIOS information. BIOS version released 8 days ago.

```
Vendor: American Megatrends International, LLC.  
Version: 1.41  
Release Date: 06/16/2022
```

Also installed a new m.2 NVMe SSD.

```
Device           Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      34   1050815   1050782 513.1M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050816 976773118 975722303 465.3G Linux filesystem

PTTYPE FSTYPE PATH           NAME      MODEL   SIZE FSAVAIL FSUSED FSUSE% LABEL MOUNTPOINT
gpt    ext4   /dev/nvme0n1p2 nvme0n1p2       465.3G    426G   7.7G     2%       /
```

I have tested this with three different OS versions. Still no Internet.

- Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Jellyfish
- Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)
- Ubuntu 20.04.4 Live  (Try ubuntu)

Output of `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED       
     description: Ethernet controller  
     product: Ethernet Connection (17) I219-V  
     vendor: Intel Corporation  
     physical id: 1f.6  
     bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6  
     version: 11  
     width: 32 bits  
     clock: 33MHz  
     capabilities: pm msi cap_list  
     configuration: latency=0  
     resources: memory:80900000-8091ffff
```

Output of `ip a`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state  
UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000  
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00  
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo  
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host   
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 4650 (rev 05)  
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 4690 (rev 0c)  
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor Gaussian & Neural Accelerator (rev 05)  
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Platform Monitoring Technology (rev 01)  
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 7ae0 (rev 11)  
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 7aa7 (rev 11)  
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 7ae8 (rev 11)  
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 7ae2 (rev 11)  
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7ab8 (rev 11)  
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7a87 (rev 11)  
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 7ad0 (rev 11)  
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 7aa3 (rev 11)  
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Device 7aa4 (rev 11)  
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (17) I219-V (rev 11)  
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Kingston Technology Company, Inc. Device 500f (rev 03)
```

Comment: The CPU and SSD details are more-or-less irrelevant to your problem - Id focus more on "Why is the Network Ibterface not being used"...

Answer (score 2):

Try enabling "Network Stack" and "Ipv4 PXE support" in the Bios!, save and reboot, go back into Bios and Disable "Network Stack", save and reboot.
Worked for me.

Lubuntu 22.04 i12-100 MSI H610 16Gb ram

Comment: Hello Robin M : your procedure works. ie. clarifying, F11 = enter setup,
settings/advanced/integrated peripherals/'network stack' = enable and
'Ipv4 PXE Support' = enable.  Save and reboot, go back into BIOS and
'Network Stack' = Disable, save and reboot.
Worked for me too.
Internet is now UP and working at full speed.
Robin, any ideas as to why this procedure works?

Comment: If I had to guess, it's because now the firmware (UEFI) is loading the firmware (Ethernet controller) that Linux may not have yet.

Comment: thanks. it worked for me too.

Answer (score 0):

`*-network UNCLAIMED`
Indicates to me that you need to find a suitable driver for the hardware involved.
Also; the "configuration:" line (in its entirety) says:
`configuration: latency=0`
... which is just another indication for the same.

An example of a working network IF is:
`configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.13.0-51-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair`

Google:
Linux Driver for Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (17) I219-V (rev 11)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with new i5 motherboard 12th generation
is internet down, giving message:
`sudo lshw -C network`
*-network UNCLAIMED

Corrective action was a band-aid, a work-around.
Corrective action was to buy an adapter.
Buy USB 3.0 adapter to ethernet RJ45 port.

But, why buy adapter when motherboard RJ45 port is
not working, giving, above error "network UNCLAIMED"?

i understand -- Buy a hardware adapter because :
RJ45 ethernet port goes to motherboard chip #1 and
RJ45 via usb  port goes to motherboard chip #2, a different chip.

Maybe someone can define chip #1 and chip #2?

In any case, i understand
ubuntu has drivers for chip #2 for RJ45 via usb port.

The adapter worked.
Purchase was worth it.
RJ45 via usb  port goes to motherboard chip #2, a different chip,
is a valid theory.

Consider adapter like a tool, a screwdriver.
Here is one adapter example:
‎TP-Link UE300

https://www.amazon.ca/TP-Link-Gigabit-Ethernet-Network-Supporting/dp/B00YUU3KC6
TP-Link Foldable USB 3.0 to 10/100/1000 Gigabit Ethernet Network Adapter, Plug & Play, Supports Windows (XP/Vista/7/8/8.1/10), Mac OS (10.11-10.14), Linux OS, Chrome OS (UE300)

Hannu suggested
Google:
Linux Driver for Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (17) I219-V (rev 11)

instead of Google
i used its competition Presearch

https://presearch.com/

and found

Intel® Ethernet Adapter Complete Driver Pack
This download installs version 27.4 of the Intel® Ethernet Adapter Complete Driver Pack for supported OS versions.
OS Independent, FreeBSD*, Linux*, Microsoft Windows*, VMware*
File: 27_4.zip
Size: 791.9 MB (791,869,826 bytes)
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/15084/intel-ethernet-adapter-complete-driver-pack.html

more testing to do, like :
move ethernet cable from usb adapter to motherboard RJ45 port
install  27_4.zip  at  791.9 MB (791,869,826 bytes)
etc ...

maybe ubuntu 20.04.4 iso will be updated
maybe ubuntu 20.04.5 iso will have driver software built in
so no manual update would be needed.

--

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this exact same Ubuntu checksum network adapter problem with an MSI Pro H610M-B DDR4 motherboard shortly after updating the BIOS. By mere chance, I enabled/disabled PXE just to see if that would fix it, and magically it did. I'm guessing Ubuntu is a bit tight with the motherboard's network firmware checksum as Windus always worked fine. The network checksum on the motherboard must have been mangled during the BIOS update. Cheers for the crosscheck tho. David.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).